# Evaluating the expression $\cos(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(-\frac{4}{3}))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I can prove that $\cos(\tan^{-1}(x)) = +\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, set $y=\tan^{-1}(x)$ and therefore $y=\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})$

Dividing both sides by $2$:

$\dfrac{y}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})$

$\cos(\dfrac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(x))=\cos(\dfrac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}))$

$\cos(\dfrac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(-\frac{4}{3}))=\cos(\dfrac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{3}{5}))$

This is my approach to the problem, are there any better ways to simplify the initial expression and perhaps find an approximation even without using a calculator?

Comment: $\arctan\frac{4}{3}=2\arctan\frac{1}{2}$, $\arctan$ is an odd function, $\cos$ is an even function, hence $$\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{-4}{3}\right)=\cos\arctan\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $\theta = \arctan\left(-\dfrac 43 \right)$

Then, from the picture, $\cos \theta = \dfrac 35$ and $\theta$ is in the fourth quadrant.

So $\cos(\frac 12 \theta) 
= \sqrt{\dfrac{1 + \cos \theta}{2}}
= \sqrt{\dfrac{1 + \frac 35}{2}}
= \dfrac{2}{\sqrt 5}$

Answer (score 3):

Inverse trig functions should always be thought of as angles.  Let $\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-4}{3}\right)$.  Then your expression is $\cos \frac{\theta}{2},$ which might suggest the half-angle identity $\cos \frac{\theta}{2} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}}.$    Since you've already evaluated $\cos \theta,$ you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Take a right-angled triangle with sides $1,x,\sqrt{1+x^2}$. The triangle exists by Pythagoras' Theorem.

The $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is its angle opposite to $x$. The cosine of that angle is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following :

$$\begin{align}
&\implies\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{-4}{3}\right)}{2}=y \\
&\implies2y=\arctan(\frac{-4}{3})\\
&\implies\tan(2y)=-4/3\\
&\implies\frac{2\tan y}{1-\tan^2y}=-4/3\\ 
&\implies2\tan^2y-3\tan y-2=0\\
\end{align}$$

Solving this equation we get-

$$\tan y=-1/2$$and $$\tan y=2$$

Using this we can find the value of $\cos y$ which will give the value of the expression. It comes out to be:

$$\cos y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Hope my answer is helpful. Sorry for any errors and please let me know if there are some.

Comment: Use \sin y, \cos y, \tan y, \csc y, \sec y, \cot y when you are in math mode to obtain $\sin y$, $\cos y$, $\tan y$, $\csc y$, $\sec y$, and $\cot y$, respectively.  Your solution makes sense until you obtain $\tan y = -1/2$ and $\tan y = 2$.  You then have to decide which solution is extraneous.  You either chose the wrong one or computed $\cos y$ incorrectly.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig I've spotted my error, and found that *tan y= -1/2* yields the correct answer as posted by others. But I'm unable to figure out why I should reject the value yielded using \tany=2 ?

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan $\tan(y)$ is negative when $y=\frac{\arctan(-\frac{4}{3})}{2}$ since $\arctan(x)$ is negative for all $x<0 \in R$ so the second solution is invalid.

Comment: Your value of $\cos y$ is still incorrect.  If $\tan y = -1/2$, then $$\sec^2y = 1 + \tan^2y = 1 + \frac{1}{4}  = \frac{5}{4} \implies \cos^2y = \frac{4}{5}$$  Since $y \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, $$\cos y = \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: @Brave Shine Thanks a lot. Thanks N.F. Taussig , I was able to spot this...